# Import a local module as component with sub components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that works 'standalone'. It allows child components to be editable (dynamically) with an 'editable' state (`editable = true` makes children editable, `editable = false` does not)

```
import Editable from './editable'

<Editable>
  <div>edit me!</div>
</Editable>
```

Next to this component I have some 'sub components' that could be used as children for the 'main component' (`Editable`). The can be used to specify other behavior for *their* children, when `Editable`'s state is set to 'editable = true'. I don't want to import these sub components all separately. I know some ways to achieve this, I will specify them below the question.

But what I'm looking for is syntax like this:

```
import Editable from './editable'

<Editable>
  <div>edit me!</div>
  <Editable.Hide>
    <div>don't show me when editable</div>
  </Editable.Hide>
  <Editable.Not>
    <div>don't make me editable when editable</div>  
  </Editable.Not>
</Editable>
```

So the export needs to be structured so that the usage of the default export will result in the main component, but (somehow) the sub components can also be accessed through that same default export.

Why? Mostly my curiosity into the possibilities and I would love to use a syntax like the above.

So is it possible to structure an export to be able to use a syntax like that?

---

These are the ways I already know how to import components with sub components:

```
import Editable from './editable'

<Editable.MainComponent>
  <div>edit me!</div>
  <Editable.Hide>
    <div>don't show me when editable</div>
  </Editable.Hide>
  <Editable.Not>
    <div>don't make me editable when editable</div>  
  </Editable.Not>
</Editable.MainComponent>
```

If I would only want the main components, I could do this with some filestructure in the `editable` folder and import like this:

```
import EditableMainComponent from './editable/mainComponent'

<EditableMainComponent>
  <div>edit me!</div>
</EditableMainComponent>
```

Or create a named export with only the main component in the same file.

```
import {EditableMainComponent} from './editable'

<EditableMainComponent>
  <div>edit me!</div>
</EditableMainComponent>
```

Another way to go is to keep only the main component as the default export and the sub components as named exports.

I am trying to avoid usage like this:

```
import Editable, {EditableHide, EditableNot} from './editable'

<Editable>
  <div>edit me!</div>
  <EditableHide>
    <div>don't show me when editable</div>
  </EditableHide>
  <EditableNot>
    <div>don't make me editable when editable</div>  
  </EditableNot>
</Editable>
```

Because I don't want the user to have to specify all the different sub components in the import. So that could also be achieved like this:

```
import { * as Editable } from './editable'

<Editable.default>
  <div>edit me!</div>
  <Editable.Hide>
    <div>don't show me when editable</div>
  </Editable.Hide>
  <Editable.Not>
    <div>Don't make me editable when editable</div>  
  </Editable.Not>
</Editable.default>
```

Comment: Hi! I noticed someone downvoted my question. I would like to know why so I won't make similar mistakes in the future!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter - but looking at close votes, someone believes that, as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: Thanks! I will try to rewrite it a little so that it becomes more clear.

Comment: I cannot say why it was downvoted but I agree that the question was asked in a form that is hard to digest, despite I'm familiar with the problem you're describing. *This would mean that I would have to import everything, even if I only want to use the MainComponent* - why do you care about that? Are other components big enough? Posting simplified code for Hide and Not would help make the question more specific (it seems to be too broad any way).

Comment: If Hide and Not are shallow containers and aren't supposed to be used apart from Editable, making them Editable properties are fine. Otherwise it's better to keep them as separate exports.

Comment: @estus, well that's pretty much what I wanted to know! How can I make them 'Editable properties'?

Comment: There should be `Editable.Not = Not` at some point where the component is defined.

Comment: @estus Perfect! Thanks, I am using functional components with Hooks however, do you also know how to do it in that case? This exactly what I wanted to know! Sorry if it was unclear with the question, I didn't know how to make it more clear. If you add your answer as an actual answer, I will accept it!

Comment: if it's in a class, I believe you can just do `Not = Not`

Comment: It's not in a class, but Estus' way was the way to do that, I was unaware of a syntax where you can just add properties to a function!

Comment: I don't think that hooks affect anything here. You are free to add properties to functions because they are objects. I added the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If components are self-sufficient and can be used separately, it's preferable to consider them of the same value and treat all of them as named exports:

```
import {Editable, EditableHide, EditableNot} from './editable'
```

If some components aren't supposed to be used apart from main component, they can be namespaced with it.

For class components:

```
class Not extends Component {...}

export default class Editable extends Component {
  static Not = Not;
  ...
}
```

For functional components:

```
const Not = props => ...;

const Editable = props => ...;
Editable.Not = Not;    

export default Editable;
```

The advantage of the last approach is that this improves testability by mocking or spying secondary components in tests, as long as they are referred as `Editable.Not` and not `Not` inside `Editable` main component.

The disadvantage of the last approach is that secondary components cannot be tree-shaken, this shouldn't be done in case their footprint is large and main component can be often used without them.